# Python code issue - trying to create a script that locates a file, edits it and saves it as a new file

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to create a script that locates my text file. Once it locates my text file, it will parse the data in the file, then save that file as a new file.

To be more specific, I have a file with a list of user information, I'd like my script to locate the username, extract it, and save it as a new file containing only usernames.

```
infile = r"C:/Highrisk/userinfo.txt"
outfile = r"C:/Highrisk/parsed.txt"
lines = []

with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        usernamestart = line.find('\\')
        usernameend = line.find(':')
        username = line[usernamestart+1:usernameend]


with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        f.write(lines[i])
```

When I execute this code, it just deletes all the text in my orignal file.

Comment: Your first loop opens the file for _writing_, and then tries to _read_ it by iterating over the lines.  Perhaps you meant to open it for reading?  Also, you never add anything to `lines`, so the second loop never executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the code working, thank you so much for all the help.

```
# Opens the allcracked.txt file, parses it and stores it as a new file 

infile = r"C:\Highrisk\crackedtest.txt"
outfile = r"C:\Highrisk\parsed.txt"
lines = []

# Locates the file, looks for the username
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        usernamestart = line.find('\\')
        usernameend = line.find(':')
        username = line[usernamestart+1:usernameend]
        lines.append(username)
print(username)

#Creates a new file with the usernames
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
     for i in range(len(lines)):
         f.write(lines[i])
         f.write("\n")
```

Comment: In that case, accept one of the answers that helped you the most (or your own...)

Answer (score 0):

When using open, 'w' is for writing and 'r' is for reading. Since it can't read the file, it just iterates over nothing and parses it as an empty file. You'll want to give it reading permissions as such:

```
infile = r"C:\test\userinfo.txt"
outfile = r"C:test\parsed.txt"
lines = []

with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        usernamestart = line.find('\\')
        usernameend = line.find(':')
        username = line[usernamestart+1:usernameend]


with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        f.write(lines[i])
```

Also, another error that you have that might be contributing is that you use the following line

```
usernamestart = line.find('\')
```

The '\' character is a special character that needs to be escaped like the following:

```
usernamestart = line.find('\\')
```

Also, you need to store the information in the first loop in a list, so you can use it when writting to the other file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the usernames in the file in the same loop that you are reading them, or to save them in a list and then output it to the file.

For writing in the file in the same loop:

```
infile = r"C:\test\userinfo.txt"
outfile = r"C:test\parsed.txt"
lines = []

## open output file to write in
fout = open(outfile, 'w') 
## read input file
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            usernamestart = line.find('\\')
            usernameend = line.find(':')
            username = line[usernamestart+1:usernameend]
            ## writing in the output file
            fout.write(username+'\n')

fout.close()
```